# I'd like a url with Sub Directory and without www to redirect to same url with www

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`example.com/category/`  should redirect to `www.example.com/category/`.

My `.htaccess` file is below.

`example.com/category/.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /category/

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```